# Back4App - Username case sensitivity

Tags: parse-platform, back4app

Is there any way to force the username column to change all entries to lowercase?

Thanks

Comment: You can write a `beforeSave` trigger to lowercase the username before saving it.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in two ways.

- SaveTrigger : In the [beforeSave](https://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide/#beforesave)() trigger of your user class, check if it is a new object, and if it is change the given username to lower case using the .toLowerCase() method like this.

`if(!request.original)`
`request.object.set("username",request.object.get("username").toLowerCase())`

- Client-side: before signing up your users just use the corresponding .toLowerCase() method for the language you are coding in and then sign the user up.